# How to declare new generic within a parameter of a TypeScript function?

Tags: typescript

Essentially, I want to remap an object using `Record`, but I'm not sure how I can access the type of the value. For example, I want something like this:

```
const testFunc = <S>(mappedObj: Record<A extends keyof S, S[A]>) => { ... }
```

The problem is I can't declare a new generic (`A`) inside of a parameter. But I need some way to know the type of the key so I can determine the type of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use mapped type directly in this case.

```js
const testFunc = <S>(mappedObj: { [P in keyof S]: S[P] }) => { ... }
```